# Removing file name between two characters bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a group of files within a directory which look like:

```
Filename - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3
```

Where there are 19 X's. I need a bash script or similar to loop and remove the X's for all of the files within my directory.

I have looked all over this site and others and have seen example using the sed command but I personally haven't been be to adapt it to my specific needs. I apologise for my lack of information, I am fairly new to this language and don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page. For verisimilitude, if you say "there are 19 X's", your example should include 19 X's.  Do you want the resulting file names to be `Filename - .mp3`, or do you want the spaces and dash removed as well as the X's?  If there were files with 18 or 20 X's, would you want them changed too, or left strictly alone?

Comment: [`rename 's/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3$/.mp3/' *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=rename)...

Comment: I'd like them to be renamed     Filename.mp3

Answer (score 0):

This is a python script that should rename all your files and remove the x's.

(You should read all the lines starting with # except the 1st one)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
for i in os.listdir("."):
    #You can change the number to whatever number of X's you want
    x = "X"*19
    #If you don't want to get rid of the ' - ', then put a '#' (without quotes) in front of the next line
    x = " - "+x
    new = i.replace(x, "")
    print(os.rename(i,new))
```

Save this file as XXX.py then give it the right permissions by doing:

```
sudo chmod +x XXX.py
```

then run it using:

```
./XXX.py
```

or if your user doesn't have the right permissions:

```
sudo ./XXX.py
```

If the program returns a error output then:

Try with sudo or try:

```
sudo python XXX.py
```

with or without sudo.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Thanks for the walk through as well. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The Python answer might be preferable as it is treacherous to copy paste "bash" one-liners from the web, but here we go:

The following for loop will:

1. list all mp3 files and select only those with 19 (bug alert: or more Xes before the extension)
2. echo each file to the screen, but removing 19 consecutive Xes first

Test:

`for FILE in *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3; do echo $(echo ${FILE} | sed -E 's/X{19}//'); done`

This baby changes the name of the files instead of "echo":

Change names:

`for FILE in *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3; do mv ${FILE} $(echo ${FILE} | sed -E 's/X{19}//'); done`

Use with caution...

Comment: It's never a good idea to [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In both examples, you could as easily do `for file in *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3; do…`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You are absolutely right and I edited my answer as you suggested, it is best to not pass on my own bad habits to the world...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `sed` for this. Just use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
for file in *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3; do
    mv "$file" "${file//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}"
done
```

If typing the Xs really bugs you…

```
printf -v Xs 'X%.0s' {1..19}
for file in *$Xs.mp3; do
    mv "$file" "${file//$Xs}"
done
```